# Meaning of "3e9 seconds" in this blog post?

Tags: meaning-in-context, mathematics

I was reading a FaceBook note, [Mastering Programming](https://www.facebook.com/notes/kent-beck/mastering-programming/1184427814923414) by a renowned software engineer Kent Beck.

This is the 2nd paragraph.

> Here are ways effective programmers get the most out of their precious 3e9 seconds on the planet.

`3e9 seconds` (300000000) roughly translates to 9.5 years according to Google.

What does `3e9 seconds` mean in this context?

Comment: You didn't convert it correctly. Add a 0, then it's 95 years.

Comment: You obviously understand the exponent nomenclature.  It looks like your confusion about the meaning stemmed from a counting error; leaving out a zero when converting to years, leading to a result without obvious meaning.  With the correct result (95 years), is the meaning obvious?  If so, consider deleting the question, as there would be nothing English-relevant, so not really applicable to the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it's 3e9 = 3*(10^9) which is about 95 years. So it would be

> Here are ways effective programmers get the most out of their precious **95 years** on the planet.

It's just a geeky, indirect way to say *time*:

> Here are ways effective programmers get the most out of their precious  **time** on the planet.

*Your/their/etc **time** on Earth* is a common expression that means *your lifetime*. Naturally, in the given text, "the planet" is Earth. The suggestion is that your lifetime is short and that you should make the most of something, like life, or in this case, programming.

95 seems kind of high, so I'm assuming the author just made up a number and that it is *not* a reference to some work, or joke, or some other thing. I assume that 3e9 just follows the theme of programming.